# Cloudformation error: "Template validation error: Invalid template parameter property 'VPC'"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I got big cloudformation json template, and trying to add VPC to it.
When I added VPC I got this error:

> Template validation error: Invalid template parameter property 'VPC'

Here the where I use VPC in Resource:

```
"VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "String",
                "EnableDnsSupport": true,
                "EnableDnsHostnames": true,
                "Tags": [
                    {"Key": "Name", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["", [{"Ref": "Env"}, "-VPC"]]}, "PropagateAtLaunch": true}
        ]
            }
        }
```

And I use "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"} in Loadbalancers, SecurityGroups PrivateSubnet, PublicSubnet in properties. 
Here is VpcId in Parameters:

```
"VpcId" : {
            "Type" : "String",
            "Description" : "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)."
        }
```

I'm not doing something very special here, but still little bit confused about error output of create stack with cloudformation.
Who can told me, what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is whole template [link](https://gist.github.com/muzaparoff/3bde1848a377a022aa9a) (without important credentials).
Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing your VPC resource is within the Parameters section of your template, but it should be in the Resources section.  You will need to share more of your template for confirmation.

Comment: @Jason I wish it was so simple :) No, it in Resource section. Any other guessing's?

Comment: I noticed you do not have a CIDR block defined.  You also should not be using the `PropogateOnLaunch` property as that is used for Auto Scaling group tags only.

Comment: Thanks @Jason . But still the same error...

Comment: Anything that uses the VPC ID should have a DependsOn (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html)

Comment: It may save you some time to aws cloudformation validate-template --templatebody file://..... not a direct answer but should give you a line and col that is giving you grief.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to close the "Parameters" block before the "Resources" block so CFN tries to create a parameter called "Resources" with a property "VPC"

Comment: Thanks man. But still didn't helped, because I checked it with jsonlint before post to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the template it looks like everything should be working fine.  Are you still getting the same issue?